# How do I import css style from ts to less in angular cli?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-cli

The reason why I need to insert styles from .ts file into less: I have a website and something like content manager panel where you can set the color of buttons for it.

Of course I can use this css variable in my html templates like:

> [style.color]="colorVar"

but maybe there is exist some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `::ng-deep` to penetrate into some component and change the styles.

```
some-component-selector ::ng-deep selector-inside-of-that-some-component {
   //write the sytles here
}
```